# images not have same height

Tags: html, css

```html
<article class="cards">
  <article class="card">
    <img class="card-image" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0306/3834/2281/files/videoImg1.png?v=423003316238239167" alt="image" />
    <div class="card-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quasi ratione odit voluptatum explicabo sit inventore, minima neque aliquam libero dolorem?</div>
    <footer class="card-footer">
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
    </footer>
  </article>

  <article class="card">
    <img class="card-image" src="https://picsum.photos/320/240" alt="image" />
    <div class="card-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <footer class="card-footer">
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
    </footer>
  </article>

  <article class="card">
    <img class="card-image" src="https://picsum.photos/1024/768" alt="image" />
    <div class="card-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, nam.</div>
    <footer class="card-footer">
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
    </footer>
  </article>
</article>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+same+image+height+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you're using flex, grid or block elements - the issue could be coming from various properties. Presuming you have no CSS added in, in the `<head>` of your html, create a style block like `<style></style>`where you may want to add your styling properties, or you could extract these to an external file if you wish to. Have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) for more information about css and how to use it .

Now back to your question, one way would be to simply add height and width properties to the `<img />` tags so you'd do something like

```
img{
  width: 300px;
  height:200px;
  object-fit:contain;
}
```

`object-fit: contain` makes sure the image doesn't get stretched.
If you'd like to see other possible solutions (such as grid or flex) please update your question

Answer (score 0):

You can add another div in img tag and give some specific height on it. also in your img give also height same as the div wrapper in your img. and do object-fit cover on it. check the code below

```css
.cards {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px
}

.card-image-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  height: 300px; /* add height to image wrapper */
 
}

.card-image {
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px; /* same height as card image wrapper */
   object-fit: cover;
   object-position: center;
}
```

```html
      <article class="cards">
        <article class="card">
          <div class="card-image-wrapper">
            <img
              class="card-image"
              src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0306/3834/2281/files/videoImg1.png?v=423003316238239167"
              alt="image"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quasi ratione odit voluptatum explicabo sit inventore, minima neque aliquam libero dolorem?
          </div>
          <footer class="card-footer">
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
          </footer>
        </article>
        <article class="card">
          <div class="card-image-wrapper">
            <img
              class="card-image"
              src="https://picsum.photos/320/240"
              alt="image"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quasi ratione odit voluptatum explicabo sit inventore, minima neque aliquam libero dolorem?
          </div>
          <footer class="card-footer">
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
          </footer>
        </article>
         <article class="card">
          <div class="card-image-wrapper">
            <img
              class="card-image"
              src="https://picsum.photos/1024/768"
              alt="image"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quasi ratione odit voluptatum explicabo sit inventore, minima neque aliquam libero dolorem?
          </div>
          <footer class="card-footer">
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
          </footer>
        </article>
      </article>
```

hope it helps and give you little idea.